# #Error in IIF formula

Tags: sql, reporting, reportbuilder3.0, iif

I am using report builder and I have created an `IIF` statement on a calculated field I have created (called Tolerance)

The field of "Tolerance" is returning a difference in time between two other fields in the format of `00:00:00`.

My IIF statement is as follows:

```
=IIF(Fields!Tolerance.Value < = "-00:10:00", "Passed","Failed")
```

This is running OK in the report but the results are all #Error.

Comment: Looks like there's a space between < and =

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but doing what you have suggested has made no improvement and is returning the same error

Answer (score 1):

You have an space between `<` and `=`. This space is not allowed, as these are not two different operators, but a single `<=` operator:

```
=IIF(Fields!Tolerance.Value <= "-00:10:00", "Passed","Failed")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but doing what you have suggested has made no improvement and is returning the same error

Answer (score 0):

Is your field `Tolerance.Value` a number?

Value `"-00:10:00"` is a string.

Try

```
=IIF(CSTR(Fields!Tolerance.Value) <= "-00:10:00", "Passed","Failed")
```

It would be helpful if you would provide samples of your `Tolerance.Value` values. This solution might only fix the `#Error` in your resulting report, but not be what you want in case `Tolerance.Value` should be formatted to similar format with your `"-00:10:00"` value.